# Is Autogenerated jQuery code from DataAnnotations an AntiPattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

From a lot of what I've been reading, it seems that you always would want to use data annotations to validate. Being a JavaScript developer, I don't always feel right about auto generated JavaScript.

Would like to get the community's take on this. First, let me explain.

If I have a flat, simple form of just textboxes that map to a class like this:

```
  public class Person
  {
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }
  }
```

The view can be pretty straightforward (bunch of textboxfor's or editfor's) and we can make that strongly typed against the Person object. If I have client side validation turned on, jQuery code is auto generated and I don't have to write a lick of code to have client side validation. "It just works," and it would be logical to do it this way if you're just dealing with this many form fields.

I think it gets very messy though, when you're dealing with a huge form (let's say an IRS or some intranet site) with over 40 form fields (sets of dropdowns, multiselect boxes, checkboxes, etc.). In addition, you could come across these scenarios which would lead to writing your own validators where the JS you write would be relying too much on your C#:

- That form could have form fields that trigger visibility of other
  form fields.
- If you have a DateOfBirth field that is set as [Required], there
  could be a button that when clicked, it makes it Unrequired
- You could be working in parallel with a designer that has to create
  new Validators but does not want to touch C# code (or data
  annotations, etc.)
- You could be working with other Validation frameworks on the web
  page.

With all these possibilities, it makes sense to not use any auto generated JavaScript (from the data annotations) and turning ClientSideValidation off, and use the jQuery Validator plugin without any C# dependency, other than just make sure the HTML elements exists and can be selectable.

Do you folks agree? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that there is no "auto generated" javascript.  Client-side validation uses jquery validation, and html data attributes, no javascript is generated.   It uses an adapter class to parse the attributes and feed them to jqv, and no.. the adapters are not auto generated.

Having said that, you're correct that data annotations are not very flexible, but it has nothing to do with jquery or auto-generation of code.  It's because data annotations are static, and created at compile time.

This is only part of the problem though.  Even if you turn off client-side validation, you still have to deal with server-side validation regardless of what client-side validation you do manually.  You never want to trust data sent by the client, so you can't ONLY do client-side validation.  You need a solution that works server-side, and hopefully also works client-side

You can use something like [fluent validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) to get more control over you validation at runtime.  this will also tie-in to the jquery validation on the client when possible.

Comment: Thanks for putting it in perspective.